# What species are the turtles?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

Tokka is specifically identified as being an alligator snapping turtle, but no specific mention of the original species of the four brothers is made.

What species of turtles were our teenage ninja heroes?

Comment: come back to agents k, thnx, bia

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are apperently Red-Eared sliders

[image]

> Within the second volume of the Tales of the Teenage Mutant Ninja
>   Turtles, the popular comic book heroes were revealed as specimens of
>   the red-eared slider.

Similarly, they are portrayed as Red-Eared Sliders in the movies:

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eared_slider)

Comment: Why yes, the resemblance is almost uncanny, I can see it now!

Comment: Nice answer. :-)

Comment: are these turtles or tortoises?